# Set hour and minute on day select using jquery datetimepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, jquerydatetimepicker

I'm trying to set time using variables using jquery datetimepicker. So the problem is the following: in my logic i've datetimepicker that can select date and time. When the user click on form field and select date only, the plugin set selected date and current time. But we have different time available set by code (for example: monday 9:00 to 12:00 (step 1 hour), tuesday 8:00 to 11:00).
So the picker doesn't have to set the current time but the first time available, for example 9:00 for monday.

When i select date only, it set also the time (but is wrong because in this case we have only 9:00 in the morning), so the result should be: 2022/04/01 09:00

[image: this is when i select day]

How can i set it up?
Below some code example:

Datetimepicker(jquery):

```
/**
 * @param currentDateTime {Date}
 */
const allowTimeOnSelectedDay = function (currentDateTime) {
    if (currentDateTime != null) {
        var currentDay = currentDateTime.getDay();
        const map1 = data.week.map(el => {
            if (el.day == currentDay) {

                let allowedTimes = generateAllowedTime(el.startingMattina, el.closingMattina, el.startingPome, el.closingPome);
                console.log(allowedTimes);
                console.log(allowedTimes[0]);
                this.setOptions({
                    allowTimes: allowedTimes
                });
            }
        });
    }
};

$('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    formatDate: 'd/m/Y H:i',
    minDate: dateToStart,
    maxDate: new Date(Date.parse(data.endDate)),
    startDate: dateToStart,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == arr[i].getMonth() && date.getDate() == arr[i].getDate()) {
                return [false, ""]
            }
        }
        return [true, ""];
    },
    onChangeDateTime: allowTimeOnSelectedDay,
    onShow: allowTimeOnSelectedDay,
    //onSelectDate : formattedDateOnSelectedDateOnly,

});
```

Comment: Please specify exactly which datetimepicker you are using, ideally within a working snippet or at least a CDN link, there are 100s with very similar UI / options.

Comment: If you only want specific times, you might be better off using a date picker to select the date with a seperate drop down with the available times.